# How can i open a window with different URLs depending of a value

Tags: custom-button, url, setup-object

First of all thank you for ur help.

Ok.

**What do I have?**

[image]

When the user clicks on "Generar Albarán Entrada" it opens a new window showing some info. I have done that window and that is not a problem.

**What do I want?**

My main problem is that i would like to have two different pages, and show the first or the second depending of the value of a field in the object:

[image]

**What did i try?**

I tried things like this:

```
{!IF({!Entrada__c.Tipo_Entrada__c == 'Anonimo', URLFOR(BA_Vista_Nueva_Entrada2,null,[no override]),null), URLFOR(/apex/BA_generarAlbaranEntrada,null, id={!Entrada__c.Id},[no override])}
```

And also, i tried to change to 'open new window' to JavaScript:

```
If('{!Entrada__c.Tipo_Entrada__c}' == 'Anonimo' && '{!Entrada__c.Modalidad__c}' == 'Rojo'){
    window.location.href = '/apex/BA_Vista_Nueva_Entrada2' ;
}
else{
    window.location.href = '/apex/BA_generarAlbaranEntrada?id={!Entrada__c.Id}'
}
```

But obviusly, code is wrong.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error ? Did you check JS errors using any editor like firebug ?

Comment: When i save the code is not getting any error, but when i try to execute it says: "Unexpected {"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if('{!Entrada__c.Tipo_Entrada__c}' == 'Anonimo' && '{!Entrada__c.Modalidad__c}' == 'Rojo'){
window.location.href = '/apex/BA_Vista_Nueva_Entrada2' ;
}
else{
window.location.href = '/apex/BA_generarAlbaranEntrada?id={!Entrada__c.Id}'
}
```

NO CAPITAL CHARACTERS FOR **IF**